# mkdir and zoxide into new directory

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, mkdir, cd

I use [`zoxide`](https://github.com/ajeetdsouza/zoxide/tree/7af4da1dabfcfc9a4b23cc8807150bf2f61a0df6) for directory navigation (i.e. as a replacement for the `cd` command) on macos. I wanted to have a simple bash function to make a new directory and then immediately `zoxide` into it.

I made a minor amendment to the nice answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125386), as follows:

```bash
mcd ()
{
    mkdir -p -- "$1" &&
       z  -P -- "$1"
}
```

Then I tried to run it in `~/Desktop` to create a completely new (i.e.,  non-existent) directory `~/Desktop/my_templates` as follows:

```bash
~/Desktop             
> mcd mytemplates
zoxide: no match found
```

The issue I believe is that zoxide doesn't realize that the new directory `mytemplates` exists yet, and thus can't navigate to it.

I also tried it by removing the `&&` to see if running `mkdir` and `z` as separate commands would help, but the same issue occurred.

Could anyone please explain how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the issue was in the line

```bash
z -P -- "$1"
```

which I changed to

```bash
z "$1"
```

Since the `-P` was a `cd` specific syntax to resolve symlinks. For zoxide, it appears that to resolve symlinks, this is done via changing the `_ZO_RESOLVE_SYMLINKS`  config setting per [here](https://github.com/ajeetdsouza/zoxide/blob/7af4da1dabfcfc9a4b23cc8807150bf2f61a0df6/README.md#environment-variables).

So the final form of the required function is now

```bash
mcd (){
    mkdir -p -- "$1" &&
    z "$1"
}
```

which works as expected.

Comment: BTW, it's possible you might want `z -- "$1"` if your directory name could start with a dash. (See Guideline 10 in section 12.2 of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - thanks again. I've amended it per your suggestion. I did test the `z "$1"` version using `mcd -mytemplates` and it did work (i.e., with a `-` at the start of the directory). This suggests that `zoxide` already adapts to directories starting with a `-`. Is this the type of corner case you wanted to cover? Just in case, I did put in your suggested version with `z -- "$1"`.

Comment: That's exactly the case, and if works without the `--` argument then you indeed don't need it.